# Проблема при изменении расстояния между слайдами в Slick.js

Tags: css, вёрстка, slick.js

Хочется изменить расстояние между слайдами, делаю это так в css:

```
.slick-slide {
    width: 330px !important;
}
```

код slick:

```
$('.top-sale-slider').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        arrows: false
});
```

После изменений прокрутка слайдов работает не корректно - перемотка не по одному слайду. Слайдер "скачет":
https://wmpics.pics/di-FUW7.gif

Подскажите, может есть другой способ изменить расстояние между слайдов или это можно исправить?

Comment: вот еще 
https://wmpics.pics/di-2JN4.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравните с нативным решением

```js
/* этот код помечает картинки, для удобства разработки */
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
      lis[i].style.position = 'relative';
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      // обычно лучше использовать CSS-классы,
      // но этот код - для удобства разработки, так что не будем трогать стили
      span.style.cssText = 'position:absolute;left:0;top:0';
      span.innerHTML = i + 1;
      lis[i].appendChild(span);
    }

    /* конфигурация */
    var width = 130; // ширина изображения
    var count = 3; // количество изображений

    var carousel = document.getElementById('carousel');
    var list = carousel.querySelector('ul');
    var listElems = carousel.querySelectorAll('li');

    var position = 0; // текущий сдвиг влево

    carousel.querySelector('.prev').onclick = function() {
      // сдвиг влево
      // последнее передвижение влево может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент
      position = Math.min(position + width * count, 0)
      list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
    };

    carousel.querySelector('.next').onclick = function() {
      // сдвиг вправо
      // последнее передвижение вправо может быть не на 3, а на 2 или 1 элемент
      position = Math.max(position - width * count, -width * (listElems.length - count));
      list.style.marginLeft = position + 'px';
    };
```

```css
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
  width: 398px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #eee;
}

.carousel img {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  /* по умолчанию inline, в ряде браузеров это даст лишнее пространство вокруг элементов */

  display: block;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}

.arrow:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  left: 7px;
}

.next {
  right: 7px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 390px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery ul {
  height: 130px;
  width: 9999px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transition: margin-left 250ms;
  /* remove white-space between inline-block'ed li */
  /* http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block */

  font-size: 0;
}

.gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div id="carousel" class="carousel">
    <button class="arrow prev">⇦</button>
    <div class="gallery">
      <ul class="images">
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/1.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/2.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/3.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/4.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/5.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/6.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/7.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/8.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/9.png"></li>
        <li><img src="https://js.cx/carousel/10.png"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button class="arrow next">⇨</button>
  </div>
```